# Number of updown sequences of $1,1,2,2,\cdots,n,n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

I would like to count the updown sequences of the set $\{1,1,2,2, \cdots, n,n \}.$
Sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ is an updown sequence if the sequence satisfies the following: $ a_1 \lt a_2 \gt a_3 \lt a_4 \gt \cdots. $

Is there any explicit formula known or any recursion formula?

Comment: google says to look at https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603520v3.pdf and Stanley says to look at http://people.brandeis.edu/~gessel/homepage/papers/dfin.pdf, but I just noticed that there equality in every second relation is allowed.

Comment: The first few terms are $1,4,53,936,25325,933980,45504649$.

Comment: I've added the counts in question (currently for $n\leq 19$) to the OEIS as https://oeis.org/A275801

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: great! Can you estimate how many terms you would be able to get with your program?

Comment: I tried to guess an algebraic diffeq, but no luck so far.

Comment: I've changed the approach and got all counts for $n\leq 50$ within a half an hour.

Comment: still no luck with an algebraic diffeq :-(